# radio button not perfectly aligned

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

who can tell me why the radio button has this strange behaviour as you can see in the picture?

[image]

it's not aligned correctly.why there is that line? I didn't applied any css style.

here it is the html code:

```
<div class = "ui-grid-a">
                    <div class = "ui-block-a">  
                        <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
                            <label for"date">Birth Date</label>
                            <input type="datetime" name="dt" id="dt" value="" placeholder="Birth Date" style="width: 50%"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "ui-block-b">
                        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                                <input type="radio" name="male" id="male" value="male" />
                                <label for="male">M</label>

                                <input type="radio" name="female" id="female" value="female" />
                                <label for="female">F</label>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: hard to tell without seeing what those css classes specify, but i would guess your answer is within those.

Comment: @pauldawg I didn't use any css class.this is the point...

Comment: @PAULDAWG this is the only css class :   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />

Comment: <div class = "ui-block-b"> is using a class. which is different than <div class = "ui-block-a">. How am I suppose to know if they have specified heights or if its the radio control margins?

Comment: So I have to overload ui-block-b propriety to avoid this problem?

Comment: This would be easier to debug with a jsfiddle example or some other live example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears as if the CSS controlling the `fieldset` surrounding your radio buttons is the culprit.  I pulled the following from the [default jQuery Mobile CSS](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.css).

```
.ui-controlgroup, fieldset.ui-controlgroup { padding: 0; margin: .5em 0 1em; }
```

There is a top margin of `.5em` and a bottom margin of `1em`.  Adjust those to see if it makes any difference at all.

Comment: @Mazzy, You're welcome.  I love it when a plan comes together.

Comment: I knew it was the fieldset! Glad this is finally resolved, and it was a CSS issue.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the css I can't say for sure, but it looks like you have a default margin set on that radio button. Try resetting it with this:

```
input {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Nothing to done. It doesn't work. As I said at the beginning of the topic. I didn't use any css particulary style. I used only jquery-mobile css style sheet

Comment: You will most likely need to use css to fix the behavior you are experiencing.

Comment: @PAULDAWG and what propriety I need to use to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

JqueryMobile automatically adds margins to the constructs it creates. I'm guessing the fieldset tags or the radio buttons themselves have additional margins from the conversion. Try adding a height property to the parent div and see if that works.

Also, the line appears when you have a narrow viewport when you use the data-role="fieldcontain". If the viewport is wider, it automatically disappears. It's JqueryMobile's way of organizing stuff around. It's usually used to group a label and its control together, so you might get a better result by not using one in that particular row of controls.

Comment: you're saying to use height css propriety?

Comment: Yup. You may have to add "!important" to override the jquerymobile classes.

Comment: the height will make the lines line up but i dont know about the label and checkboxes lining up because of a height change. why are the checkboxes in a fieldset? can you use a div instead maybe?

Comment: @PAULDAWG Ok the height set up the line but the checkbox is not aligned to the near input text.

Comment: @PAULDAWG: I believe it's jquerymobile's way to group the two radiobuttons together and display them horizontally as it is at the moment.

Comment: @Mazzy: Check the classes using Firebug or your browser's equivalent and override the margin or padding values.

Comment: @PAULDAWG I tried to change the fieldset with a div but the checkbox remain the same.I have to align the checkbox. some ideas?